# Unknown authentication response: 10 Postresql golang

Tags: postgresql, go, http, backend

I get an error while connect to postresql with golang

ERROR -----------  pq: unknown authentication response: 10

CODE:

```
cfg := config{
    Host:     "localhost",
    Port:     5432,
    Username: "postgres",
    Password: "ellez2004",
    DBname:   "app",
}
pconfig := fmt.Sprintf("host=%s port=%d user=%s password=%s dbname=%s sslmode=disable",cfg.Host,cfg.Port,cfg.Password,cfg.Password,cfg.DBname)
db,err := sql.Open("postgres",pconfig)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err.Error())
}
defer db.Close();

insert := `insert into "User" ("firstname","lastname") values('Allaz','Bairamov')`
_ ,err = db.Exec(insert);
if err != nil { 
    fmt.Println("error ---", err.Error());
}
fmt.Println("success");
http.ListenAndServe(":8000", nil)
```

Please help:)

Comment: What is your sql driver version? mysql and postgres version also ?

Comment: Postgres version is 14

Answer (score 1):

Seems like there is typo. Should be .Username not .Password

```golang
pconfig := fmt.Sprintf("host=%s port=%d user=%s password=%s dbname=%s sslmode=disable",cfg.Host,cfg.Port,cfg.Password,cfg.Password,cfg.DBname)
```

Else, try make sure all the parameters tally with Postgres Connection

```golang
    Host:     "localhost", // where you host your Postgres server
    Port:     5432, // default port for Postgres
    Username: "postgres", // this is user credential to access of the database
    Password: "ellez2004", // corresponding password
    DBname:   "app", // the database schema name
```